# Naked Domain with Heroku and BigRock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, cname, wildcard-subdomain

I have my domain name `example.com` from domain registrar **BigRock**, which also provides me the DNS management panel.
My application is hosted at **Heroku** at `example.herokuapp.com`.

Domain Settings at Heroku:

```
bash-3.2$ heroku domains
=== MyApp Domain Names
*.example.com
example.herokuapp.com
example.com
www.example.com
```

In my DNS Management panel, I have 0 A records, 1 MX records for Hotmail and 1 CNAME record for `www.example.com`.

I know about the problem with Naked domains and A-records with Heroku.
I have gone through these:
1. [StackOverflow ques - How to setup DNS for an apex domain (no www) pointing to a Heroku app?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16041655/355722)
2. [Heroku DevCenter - Custom domains - set up root domain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#root-domain)
3. [Heroku DevCenter - Apex Domains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains)

The above links and many others point towards 2 solutions:

- Using ALIAS or ANAME records by DNSimple/ DNS Made Easy
- If your DNS provider does not support such a record-type, and you are unable to switch to one that does, you will need to use subdomain redirection to send root domain requests to your app on Heroku.

Since, I couldn't find such records on BigRock DNS Management Console. There were only these records - "A, AAAA, MX, CNAME, TXT, SRV and SOA".

Accordingly, I have setup "**Domain Forwarding**" for my domain. But, it only gave me option to provide "*Designation URL where you wish to forward requests for www.example.com and example.com*".

Now, If I do

```
bash-3.2$ host example.com
example.com has address 173.194.16.11
example.com mail is handled by 15 888379351a9a.pamx1.hotmail.com.
```

and

```
bash-3.2$ host www.example.com
www.example.com is an alias for example.herokuapp.com.
```

This does solve the naked domain problem. But other subdomains like `xyz.example.com` are still not redirected to `www.example.com`, because 
there is no mention to redirect all subdomains i.e "*" to any other designation in the "Domain Forwarding" section on BigRock DNS provider.

**So, my question is how can I solve this problem of redirecting sub-domains?**

> Another Query Related to SSL -

Here in the [Heroku Devcenter - subdomain redirection](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#subdomain-redirection), it says that
*"However, be aware that, using this method, a secure request to the root domain, e.g., https://example.com, will result in an error or warning being displayed to the user."*

Is there any way of fixing the above issue, or do I have to switch to DNSimple or DNS Made Easy to use the ALIAS or ANAME records services they provide?

**UPDATE:**
On further digging, I found this SO ques - [Rails Manually redirecting from Naked Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536724/rails-manually-redirecting-from-naked-domain), which suggests using:

- [Rack_rewrite](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite)
- [Refraction gem](https://github.com/joshsusser/refraction)

Is this a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you setup a domain forward in BigRock DNS panel, you will see two A records like `example.com => 173.193.106.11` and  `www.example.com => 173.193.106.11`. The same way if you create wildcard dns A record, it will redirect for all the domains. i.e `*.example.com =>  173.193.106.11`

I am not sure if the IP is same in your case because Bigrock might be using multiple servers to offer this service.

Comment: Thanks Waqar for your reply. Yes, Bigrock did create 2 A records as you have mentioned. But, A records are bad when it comes to hosting with Heroku as mentioned here - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains#limitations

Comment: Please correct me if I'm missing something obvious here. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Jatin, this IP address is from Bigrock, not from Heroku and I am sure, Bigrock is not going to change their redirection service server's IP without notification. I am using this redirection service and I am sure that it will fulfil your purpose too

Comment: Thanks. I'm going forward with what you've suggested. I'll keep the bounty open so that it still gathers attention from more people while it can.

Answer (score 1):

Linode do not offer naked domain ANAME records either. A solution I have found is to add a www.site.com CNAME record for the Heroku app as normal. Then point the naked domain/catch-all A record to the following IP address:

```
174.129.25.170
```

This is a free naked domain redirect service offered by [wwizer](http://wwwizer.com). It will take your naked domain, and simply redirect it to a www. equivalent:

```
site.com => www.site.com
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Andy, but right now I'm going forward with @Waqar's solution because for wildcard domains I have to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your domain name with `www` in the 'Destination' of Domain Forwarding Panel.
Later, remove the A record for `www`. Hence, there will only be 2 A records

i.e for naked domain and wildcard (*)

Then add a CNAME record for `www` pointing to the `HerokuApp` value.
Do let us know if you are facing any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do `Domain Forwarding` of your site from naked domain to www sub domain. This features available next to `Manage DNS` feature. Once the dialog open, just enter your www subdomain(`www.example.com`). After 6 to 8 hours(sometime it take 1 day), It will automatically add an `A record` for your naked domain(`example.com`) points to ip `173.193.106.14`.

Answer (score -1):

For e.g. kanhaiyakumawat.com and kanhaiyakumawat.herokuapp.com

Here are the steps

- Add records in your heroku account for
- www.kanhaiyakumawat.com to kanhaiyakumawat.herokuapp.com
- kanhaiyakumawat.com to kanhaiyakumawat.herokuapp.com
- *.kanhaiyakumawat.com to kanhaiyakumawat.herokuapp.com

So now with this heroku side setup is done. Lets move to bigrock 'DNS Management' section. Click 'Manage DNS'.

- Add CNAME Records
- www.kanhaiyakumawat.com to kanhaiyakumawat.herokuapp.com
- *.kanhaiyakumawat.com to kanhaiyakumawat.herokuapp.com

**MOST IMPORTANT: Setting up Naked Domain or root domain Setup**

- Now this is most trickiest part. Just leave the 'hostname' text box
  empty and select 2nd radio button in Values.
- Put here your heroku dns value e.g. kanhaiyakumawat.herokuapp.com

Same steps are available here:
http://kanhaiyakumawat.com/blog/heroku-and-bigrock-dns-setup/